# Upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04 and have to transfer database from Postgresql 8.4 to 9.1

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I upgraded a server with a Rails application to Ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04 and cannot connect to `Postgresql` database now...

Here is the error message from Rails app:

`could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"`

Also the `pg_ctl start` is not recognized as a command.

**EDIT**:

Turns out my database is on `Postgresl 8.4` and my sever is now running on 9.1. So all the database files / configs are on 8.4..

How can I transfer them? Just straight copy from old `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should *probably* start with the [Postgres documentation on upgrading to 9.1.x](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html).

I can tell you two things for certain:

1. It is more complicated than just copying a few files around.
2. This is something you should have investigated and planned ***before*** you did your server upgrade.
   (think of the annoying process you now have to go through as an object lesson in proper planning)

---

Considering your situation, every upgrade path will require you to install appropriate 8.4.x binaries.  You will probably be best served by using the [pg_upgrade process](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgupgrade.html), as it will be less time-consuming than a dump/restore in most cases.

Of course before you do anything else you should ***`MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR POSTGRES DATA DIRECTORY`***. The data (and job) you save may be your own...